# Organizing Resources for a Java Game

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, embedded-resource

I'm currently writing a Java game for PC, and I have a question about where the resources (images, sounds, data, ect.) should be located. For most PC games, the game's main directory looks something like this:

```
GameName
 ├─ Resource Directory
 │   └── ...
 ├─ More Resources
 │   └── ...
 .
 .
 └── GameName.exe
```

The resources are organized into different directories, with the game's main `.exe` file, and possibly a few other files, in the game's main directory. However, in my Intellij project, I have put all my resources in the project's `resources` directory. It's my understanding that, when I build my game into a `.jar` file, all of the resources in the `resources` directory will be packed into the `.jar` file as well.

So, is there any reason why I would want to separate all my resources into different subdirectories within the game's main directory, rather than simply keeping them all contained within the game's `.jar` file? If so, how do I keep Intellij from packing all the resources into the `.jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People separate it mostly because it is easier to update. If you have everything in your Jar, that will be one big file that you have to replace every time you want to update a resource. But if you store your assets separately, your launcher can update only the files needed, without touching the game.

You can't tell IntelliJ to stop placing them inside your Jar. You have to stop placing them in there. Don't put your resources in your Jar, but into a separate directory, and instead of `getClass().getResource()` you use a `File` object and open that. You have to make sure the file exists before using it.